# CMake can't find minizip but I can use zlib

Tags: c, zip, zlib, minizip

I'm trying to use minizip in the zlib library.  I'm compiling on CentOS and got zlib using

```
yum -y install zlib-devel
```

The problem is, when compiling (and linking to the libz.so library file), it looks like I can get everything in zlib, but none of the header files or function for minizip can be found.  For example, `find_package(ZLIB REQUIRED)` works, and so does `#include <zlib.h>`, but `#include <minizip/zip.h>` returns file not found.

Following the instructions from John's blog on minizip https://nachtimwald.com/2019/09/08/making-minizip-easier-to-use/

`pkg_check_modules(MZIP minizip REQUIRED)` is giving me minizip not found.

Looking at `rpm -ql zlib-devel` gives

```
/usr/include/zlib.h
/usr/lib64/libz.so
```

I thought everything in minizip would just be part of libz.so?   Or do I need to do something more to link to minizip?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, minizip is not part of the zlib library. It is included in the zlib source code distribution, along with several other third-party contributions, in the `contrib/` directory.

You would need to compile it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the response!   Are the yum install minizip-devel packages still outdated, or are they also up to date now?

Comment: I have no idea. I don't even know what "yum" is, except something I say after eating ice cream.